# Why the induced metric from the lie algebra of lie group $G$ is left invariant.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, riemannian-geometry

we say that a Riemannian metric on $G$ is left invariant if 
$\langle u,v\rangle_y = \langle d(L_x)_y u,d(L_x)_y v\rangle_{L_x(y)}$
to introduce a metric on $G$, take any arbitrary inner product $\langle , \rangle_e$ on the lie algebra of lie group and define
$\langle u,v\rangle_x = \langle d(L_{x^{-1}})_x(u),d(L_{x^{-1}})_x (v)\rangle_e$, where $x\in G, u,v\in T_x G$
So, why it is left invariant?

Comment: That follows from $L_{x_1x_2} = L_{x_1}\circ L_{x_2}$,

Comment: @ArcticChar I must missing something, could you please give me more information?

Comment: If you plug in your definition (second equation) into your first equation, there will be a composition of $d(L_{x^{-1}})$ with $d (L_y)$, then the equation I stated will be helpful in simplifying the term.

Comment: @ArcticChar only obtain this $d(L_{{xy}^{-1}})_{xy} d(L_y)_x u$ then I cannot use your formula.

Comment: The second term should be $d(L_x)_y$

Comment: @ArcticChar sorry, I still cannot figure it out when we use this smbol to denote the tangent map

Comment: @ArcticChar I see it. Thx

Comment: If you solve the question already, you may post an answer.

Comment: @ArcticChar I write the answer you supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\langle u,v\rangle_b = \langle d(L_a)_b u,d(L_a)_b v\rangle_{ab}$

Is this equation true?

By our definition of inner product on arbitrary point, which is defined via the inner product on the tangent plane on the uint element of the Lie group, the only equation we have to verified is

$\langle d(L_{b^{-1}})_b(u),d(L_{b^{-1}})_b (v)\rangle_e = \langle d(L_{(ab)^{-1}})_{ab} \circ d(L_a)_b u , d(L_{(ab)^{-1}})_{ab}\circ d(L_a)_b v \rangle_e$

However, it follows from these two facts:

- $L_{xy} = L_x \circ L_y$
- $d(F\circ G)_p = dF_{G(p)}\circ dG_p$, where $G: M\to N$, $F: N\to P$, and $p\in M$